# Gravitational Force in a two hollow identical spheres?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, newtonian-gravity, mass, symmetry

**Two identical hollow spheres of negligible thickness are placed in contact with each other. the force of gravitation between the spheres will be proportional to (r = radius of each sphere):**

1. R
2. R²
3. R⁴
4. R³

Comment: Spherical symmetry can assume the masses are point masses for easier computation. $$|F|= \frac{GM_{1}M_{2}}{(2R)^2}$$ $$M_{1}=\rho 4\pi R^2$$ $$M_{2}=\rho 4\pi R^2$$ so $$|F| \propto \frac{R^2 R^2}{R^2} \propto R^2$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: as $r$ changes the mass of each spherical shell changes, as well as the distance between their centres (I think you have to assume that the material out of which the spherical shells are made has a constant density, and the thickness of the shells is also constant).

Comment: Hey friend, can u give me complete answer for this question as i have to pass this answer to my friend who just did it wrong in her mock examination by considering it as solid sphere but here the word hollow is doing the trick i think so. Hoping to get an complete answer.

Comment: @MayankBhatt The question says the "spheres" have "negligible thickness", so they are actually spherical shells where the thickness of each shell is very small compared with its radius. If they were solid spheres then the mass of each sphere would be proportional to $r^3$. But since they are spherical shells, their mass is proportional to a lower power of $r$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Since the spheres are hollow with negligible thickness, their mass is proportional to their surface area (we assume that the thickness is infinitesimally small). If they were solid, it would be proportional to their volume. Now you can substitute for the mass in terms of areal density and surface area and get the answer.

I hope this helps.